# Can't hide ui through onClick()

Tags: android

I want to make the navigationbar, titlebar and infobar disapear. When I call hideUi() through a Handler.postDelay() its working fine. But when i call it through a OnClickListener.onClick() only the titlebar disapears.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             if(uiIsHidden) {
                 showUi();
             } else {
                 hideUi();
             }
         }
});

private void hideUi() {
    uiIsHidden = true;
    actionBar.hide();
    mediaController.hide();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a Handler in OnClickListener?

Comment: Does it show some warning/error/something in Logcat when you don't do it in `Handler`?

Comment: Ow this is just a leftover from what i've tried before. I previously post hideUi as delayed into this handler. Sadly that did only change something when the delay was just to long.

Comment: This question is missing details. You haven't mentioned anything from Logcat and your comment makes it confusing as well. You should add such information in your original question. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I know more now. I wanted to do Leanback mode, not immersive. Also i had to set the window flags itself. Otherwise android acts strange.
More info can be found here: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html